# How to download and use PhonenumberUtil

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, libphonenumber

I found this library https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/ and wanted to use it in my project, but how to I install/download this library in Eclipse and how do I use it with my own project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should download it from this link. http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/googlecode/libphonenumber/libphonenumber/

And put code into your application. Import this package in the activity program and use it.

Answer (score 3):

Like @stephen mentioned, you can directly download the jar of the latest version from [this](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/googlecode/libphonenumber/libphonenumber/) link

**OR**

If you want to avoid the hassle of downloading and importing it as a package, just check the `latest version number` from the same link and replace `x.y.z` with it in your build.gradle

```
 compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:x.y.z'
```

Example: As of today (April 12, 2017), the latest version number in the link says 8.4.1, so the above line would look like this -

```
compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.4.1'
```